# gremlin traversal on AWS neptune

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I have a graph structure like this-

```
Node1(Console)   <----Uses---  Node2(Name, Age) -----plays----> Node3(Game)
```

So, i have three nodes -

Node1 is console like a PS3/ Nintendo.

Node2 is a person with properties name and Age.

Node3 is game node which holds game name like 'warcraft'.

Now I want to have a gremlin query which tells me that.
How many users (Node2) who has the console like PS3, plays a game like 'warcraft'

I think i need to start the traverse from Node2 , filter it based on Node1 property i.e console as as 'PS3' and plays game like 'warcraft'

I am new to gremlin and using some thing like this -

```
g.V().hasLabel('user').outE('uses').inV().has('console', 'ps3').count()
```

the above query only answers half of my required result. How do i filter Node2 based on plays relationship as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to write the query.

**Option 1: Start from console**

`g.V().has('console', 'ps3').in('uses').where(out('plays').has('game', 'warcraft')).valueMap('name')`

Let me explain the structure here:

`g.V().has('console', 'ps3')` --> Select all vertices which have a property with key as `console` and value as `ps3`

`in('uses')` --> From the set of previous vertices, jump to incoming vertices via an edge that has the label `uses`. At this stage, we would have player vertices in our solution.

`where(out('plays').has('game', 'warcraft'))` --> Apply a filter on existing solutions. Since we are using `where` we would not jump/traverse to the next step of vertices.

`valueMap('name')` --> Project one or more properties if existing solutions which are player vertices.

**Option 2: Another way to write above query**

`g.V().has('console', 'ps3').in('uses').as('myusers').out('plays').has('game', 'warcraft').select('myusers').by('name')`

`as('myusers')` --> Provides a reference/alias to the vertices at this stage. Note that it does not store all the results at this stage instead it just provides a reference to the type of vertices at this point in the query.

`out('plays').has('game', 'warcraft')` --> Unlike previous time when we did not jump since we were using `where`, this time we jump onto the `game` vertices.

`select('myusers').by('name')` --> since we want to project the users but the current solutions are game vertices, we need to select the user vertices which we do using the reference we stored earlier.

**Option 3: Start from user**

`g.V().hasLabel('user').where(out('plays').has('game','warcraft')).where(out('uses').has('console','ps3')).valueMap('name')`

There are more ways to write this query such as using `path()` but I won't go into details here.

Since you are beginning to learn Gremlin, I would recommend that you start with https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation, it is really helpful.